# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 for pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have searched on SO and found similar questions but there suggest to add framework from Link Binary With Libraries in compile sources. But in my case undefined symbols are for libraries installed using Cocoa pods.

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and used Cocoa pods to integrate `AFNetworking`, `SWRevealViewController` and `MRProgressView` in my project. When I build the project for `iPhone` simulator it works fine and runs too. But when the target simulator device is `iPad 2` it generates errors shown in following image.

[image: Generated errors]

I have done following things to resolve but none of them worked for me.

- Removing and reinstalling all pods.
- Used pod repo remove master and pod setup
- Checked Compile Sources for all pod target which contains the `.m` files shown as undefined symbol in error.
- Created test project, install `AFNetworking` using Cocoa pods and build and run the project for `iPad 2` and it works fine.

I don't understand what is the problem. Any help or other suggestion is appreciated.